# create google maps url in php

Tags: php, url

I Have a database with latitude and longitude values, I´m trying to write a PHP file that gets these values and then create links to google maps, so when I run the PHP file the values can be clicked pointing to google maps with the latitude and longitude values.

I never worked with PHP before and I cannot make it work, and I will be very thankful if anyone here can help me, please.

Here is the code I´ve written so far:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>message</th>
<th>location</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";


echo "<td>" . '<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:', urlencode $row['location'], '">' . "</td>";



echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: In what way does this fail?

Comment: where are the `latitude and longitude values`?

Comment: the latitude and longitude values are on the database, in the row called "location"

Comment: David, the error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in list.php on line 35

Comment: `', urlencode $row['location'], '` to `'. urlencode ($row['location']). '` and check for more errors, better use a dev tool like netbeans

Comment: @Vladimir: You're trying to use commas to concatenate your strings.  Everywhere in the code you're using periods, which is the correct operator to use for this.  Just use periods on that line too.

Answer (score 1):

the error code is telling you whats up. Look at line 35. You arent concatenating correctly. You need to change

```
echo "<td>" . '<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:', urlencode $row['location'], '">' . "</td>";
```

To

```
echo '<td><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:'. urlencode($row['location']) . '"></td>';
```

Have a read up on [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: have updated my answer. `urlencode` needs brackets round the var to be encoded

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't it also be  loc= rather than loc: